# Закругленный бордер с градиентом

Tags: html, css

Хочу создать закругленный бордер с градиентом. В интернете прошерстил и нашел лишь то, что вся эта прелесть легко делается с .svg, что мне не хотелось бы использовать, однако, у меня выходит лишь с использованием второго блока или же псевдоклассом :before. Но оба эти варианта можно использовать в том случае, если цвет фона сплошной. Можно ли как-нибудь накладывать градиент на сам бордер? Пробовал и -webkit'ы, но тщетно.

```css
.block_after {
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, pink 0%, blue 50%);
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.block_before {
  background: #222222;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_after">
  <div class="block_before">
    Текст
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Закругленный бордер вокруг текста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вы ищете что-то вроде `-webkit-text-stroke`.

Мой пример стоит [посмотреть тут](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbbrox), если в SO не работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: 'Intro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, pink 0%, blue 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 10px transparent
  
  color: #222222;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Совместимость:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пример хороший, возьму на заметку, но мне нужнен бордер вокруг текста.

Comment: @НикитаБорискевич Можете, пожалуйста, нарисовать пример того, что вы хотите видеть? border вокруг текста - обычно имеется ввиду `border: Npx solid COLOR;`.

Comment: к вопросу прикреплён код. Вот нечто подобное мне и нужно.

Comment: @НикитаБорискевич то есть вы хотите *отцентрировать* ваш код? Очень трудно понять что вы хотите в итоге, но я пытаюсь уловить вашу идею)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Fyuuri/h8xk73d2/
Вот там примерчик и то, что нужно поменять.